# Reactjs : What is different between create a component by function and by name of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with the function inside the nested component the doSomething function is not triggered when I use it with

```
const Container = ({content}) => {
    const Item = () => {
        return <ItemContainer>{content}</ItemContainer>
    }

    return <div>
              <Navbar />
              <Item />
           </div>
}

const Main = () => {
    return <Container content={<button onClick={doSomething}>abc</button>} />
}
```

But when I use Item as a function. It solve the problem. But I don't know what is the magic here. Could someone help me explain it?

```
const Container = ({content}) => {
    const Item = () => {
        return <ItemContainer>{content}</ItemContainer>
    }

    return <div>
              <Navbar />
              {Item()}
           </div>
}
```

Comment: there is no function for doSomething.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it is mock function. I can bring whole the code here.

Comment: Thanks @Fallen I can solve the problem with second approach. But I just want to know why it works :)

Comment: I think if you pass button tag as arrow function will fix first approach 
sth like this : content={()=><button>abc<button>}

Comment: In my case, the real structure doesn't work with that approach and I can fix it with the second approach I wrote in description. But I also want to know the different between 2 ways of creating a component. Anyway thanks @AliSattarzadeh